# What steps should I take to use GitHub copilot in my work?

Tags: ethics, code

A few weeks ago I got access to GitHub copilot, probably many of you have seen hundreds of news about GitHub copilot, if you do not know, in essence it is a kind of AI that helps you create code, I have been thinking for a few days that it really is. The only use I can give it is at work since outside of my working hours I don't usually schedule anything.

Then of course, I have a problem, if I make code using that tool, which is under use licenses that allow its commercial use, I should indicate it somewhere, communicate it to my company, I do not see it so different from copying a fragment of Stack Overflow, or a random tutorial out there, or even the autocompletion that IDE like Intellijs give us, but that, I don't know what steps to follow to use it in my work. Or how correct would it be to use it without telling anyone in my company.

Comment: There is normally be a common procedure of using opensource tools and libraries. It is reasonable to ask your manager about this procedure.

Comment: I think you should use another forum, like the regular stack exchange. Also, you need to edit this! It appears some text got cut out mid paragraph.

Comment: Do you fully own the code "generated" by that tool?

Answer (score 11):

Generally, you shouldn't be using any tools or services without talking to someone in your company, like your manager, first. This includes installing software packages on your work computer, using web-based services to track company work related to proprietary efforts, or generating code. You need to make sure that you are in compliance with all of the licenses of the tools, otherwise you are putting yourself and your company at risk.

A tool like [GitHub Copilot](https://copilot.github.com/) raises even more questions than some tools, based on how it was trained. Since it was trained on a wide set of code uploaded to GitHub, that includes source code licensed under strong copyleft licenses like GPL and AGPL as well as source code without a license where copyright is maintained by the author. There may be implications if enough code like this ends up added to your project. Since it's autogenerated code, there are also risks of security vulnerabilities that you may not be aware of being injected.

I'd also point out that GitHub Copilot is still in "Technical Preview". It's not widely available. This preview is being used to assess the technical capabilities (and limits) as well as get more insight into how such a tool is received by various stakeholders. There may be unknown issues, technical, legal, or ethical, that come up as people explore the capabilities.

If you think that it could be a useful tool to investigate, talk to your manager. Get permission to use it in your daily work. If you don't get permission to use it for work, don't use it for work. If you're interested in experimenting, find a way to use it on a personal project.

Answer (score 3):

> I don't know what steps to follow to use it in my work.

This seems to boil down to licenses. Check the license, see it's restrictions and requirements, and act accordingly.

> I do not see it so different from copying a fragment of Stack Overflow,

Remember that (if I recall correctly) the whole SE network is CC BY SA v4 so there are things to consider if you are using it. Mainly to give appropriate credit and to use the same license if you do derivative works.

See: https://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/4.0/

Finally, we can check the official page on GitHub Copilot and find many answers there (https://copilot.github.com/). Putting some of those here:

> **Do I need to credit GitHub Copilot for helping me write code?**
>
> No, the code you create with GitHub Copilot’s help belongs to you. While every friendly robot likes the occasional word of thanks, you are in no way obligated to credit GitHub Copilot. Just like with a compiler, the output of your use of GitHub Copilot belongs to you.

> **Who owns the code GitHub Copilot helps me write?**
>
> GitHub Copilot is a tool, like a compiler or a pen. The suggestions GitHub Copilot generates, and the code you write with its help, belong to you, and you are responsible for it. We recommend that you carefully test, review, and vet the code, as you would with any code you write yourself.

Comment: Yeah... I don't trust this at all. Someone needs to do an empirical analysis on its output and run it by a bunch of lawyers before I trust my entire career on a tool that creates code. Just because GitHub claims the code is yours, it doesn't mean it is. Does GitHub offer a chunk of money for liability when a user is sued? If not, their statement means nothing.

Comment: I mean this in the most serious way. Let's say you hired a consultant, and he gives you copyrighted code. Under normal law, that consultant is liable because he is a legal entity that has responsibility, and can be sued. However, since an AI is current not a legal entity, the legal framework cannot handle what happens, and you have absolutely no guarantee that code isn't stolen by the AI because that level of understanding and analysis is not even possible yet. If copyrighted code is found in the training data, what happens? Do the copyright holders own ALL the stuff the AI creates?

Comment: Further to what Nelson said, typically what would happen is the aggrieved party would sue the company, and then the company would sue the consultant to cover their own damages. The aggrieved party doesn't care how the company came to use the code, the fact is the company used copyrighted code. Maybe the company could go after GitHub because they said "the code belongs to you", but I'm sure in the tiny tiny fine print there is something that makes them not liable.